# Paypal Express logo (new style)

Tags: paypal

When I first installed Magento 1.9.0.1 and activated Paypal Express Checkout, I saw the new style logo as shown on this page:

https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/logos-buttons

But for reasons I can't explain my store now shows the old style logo, which in my opinion looks less modern.

The logo shown is this one:
https://fpdbs.paypal.com/dynamicimageweb?cmd=_dynamic-image&buttontype=ecshortcut&locale=en_GB&ordertotal=29.95&pal=MOO

Anyone know why this could be?  I don't remember changing anything in the backend that would affect this?

Answer (score 2):

The logo come directly from PayPal. 
You can change it from app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/paypal/express/shortcut.phtml 
look for:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getImageUrl()?>" alt="<?php echo Mage::helper('paypal')->__('Checkout with PayPal');?>" />
```

and replace the src.